# Can the object passed into a Rails route change the hostname?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I want:

```
channel_url(channel_object)       # http://domain1.com/something/here
channel_url(other_channel_object) # http://domain2.com/something/here
```

Basically, the object passed into channel_url should be able to change the hostname.

I could do this by defining a helper method called `channel_url`, but I'd much rather use the generated rails routes methods.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done with routing out of the box. Routes are made to deal with routes within the application. Even subdomains are not really part of it.

You could alter the `url_to` method from `ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper` to look at the object passed into it.

```
def url_for(options={})
  if options.respond_to? :domain
    super options, domain: options.domain
  else
    super
  end
end
```

Something like that, given that your `channel_object` responds to domain. :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: My application serves multiple domains, btw, so it's still considered "within the application".

Comment: Seems like this could be done by the `to_param` method returning either a string OR an object that responds to `path`, `domain`, etc. `url_for` could look for that.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I meant `url_for` :)

I know using subdomains is common, it just seems subdomains are not really out-of-the-box in Rails routing.

You're right about the `to_param` part as well.